# Total all counts foreach count in php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

The code selects department, which then lists courses in that department, i then want the total amount of resources for linked courses (parent and child courses) to also be echoed.

I am trying to get a Total sum from foreach count in php array.
Can anbody help me with this please?

Here is my code:

```
$categoryid = $_POST['dept'];

//get course codes from department
$get_dept_codes = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM course_categories WHERE parent = 0 order by name asc");


    echo "<form method='POST' action='gsb_by_department.php'><p>";
    echo "<select size='1' name='dept'>";
    //loop through and list department names in drop down box
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_dept_codes))
        {
        $catid = $row['id'];
        $catname = $row['name'];
        echo "<option name='category' value=$catid>$catname</option>";

        //echo $catid;
        //echo $catname;
        echo "<br />";
        }



echo "</select><input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit'></p></form>";


//get course codes from department

$get_dept_codes = mysql_query("SELECT course.id, course.shortname, course.fullname, gsb_content.gsb
FROM _course INNER JOIN gsb_content ON course.id = gsb_content.courseid
WHERE (((course.category)=$categoryid)) AND course.metacourse = 0
ORDER BY course.id;");

//loop through and process for courses 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_dept_codes))
    {

$childcourse = $row['id'];

//Get the $parentcourses

    $parentcourses= mysql_query("SELECT parent_course FROM course_meta where child_course = $childcourse"); 

//for each of the $parentcourses count FROM resource where course=$theparentcourse

    foreach($parentcourses as $parentcourse)) {
    $thenewid = $parentcourse['parent_course'];
    $thecount = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM resource where course=$thenewid");
    }

//I want to be able to add up all the counts from the above and store in variable 

    $allcountstandardslinknum = array_sum($countstandardslinknum);
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas/guidance.
Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just funky code, or a bug, but the line starting with `$thecount` ISN'T in your foreach like this, because of not using staches (`{`) with your foreach.....

Comment: why has this got minus 2? Are we marked down for guidance/help?

Comment: As it was it wasn't very clear: you'd expect that you state what you want, add your current code (minimized as possible) and tell us what goes wrong. As it currently is, it's just a big lump of code without a question. That's not how stuff works. There isn't even a question mark anymore. As it was, it was just a not very well stated problem, but as it is, it might justify a close vote even. PLease actually ask a question: start with what you want, tell us what you have and your code, and finish with what your problem is.

Comment: @:Nanne: Sorry, i have modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the above was meant as pseudo code but the `mysql_query` method returns a result object so you need to do something like `mysql_fetch_array`.

As for getting the total you can just sum in your loop like so:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($parentcourse as $parentcourses)) {
    $thenewid = $parentcourse['parent_course'];
    $thecountrow = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM resource where course=$thenewid"));
    $thecount = $thecountrow[0];
    $total += $thecount;
}
echo "Total is $total";
```

You may also want to add sanity checking and the like too.

Edit:
Also just noticed your foreach loop has the variables the wrong way, it should be:

```
foreach($parentcourses as $parentcourse){
```

I always remember this as a sentence: "for each of the items in $parentcourses name $parentcourse"

Edit2:
Your $parentcourses variable isn't actually an array you need to grab each row in a similar way to your outer while loop something like:

```
$parentcoursesres= mysql_query("SELECT parent_course FROM course_meta where child_course = $childcourse"); 
$total = 0;
while($parentrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($parentcoursesres)){
    $thenewid = $parentrow['parent_course'];
    $thecountrow = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM resource where course=$thenewid"));
    $thecount = $thecountrow[0];
    $total += $thecount;
}
echo "Total is $total";
```

Comment: This seems like what im after, it is returning 0 though. I think the mysql_query for $parentcourses is returning nothing, but when i run the SQL command in phpmyadmin i get 19 rows. Would it make a difference if the mysql_query for $parentcourses is in a while loop?                                                            //loop through and process for courses in divisions
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getcoursedivs))
 {
  $childcourse= $row['id'];

Comment: The code which grabs $parentcourse will need to be changed also. Will update the answer.

Comment: I have modded my question to include the loop through and process for courses in divisions

Comment: Have updated the answer following your edit. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Works brilliantly, thank you very much for your help, it was greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Jim, just realised that adds up all of the $parentrow courses but does not include the child course count. So i need to add mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM resource where course=$childcourse"); to the count.Theres only one so do i place it outside the while loop and just add to $total?

Comment: @Codded Yeah, that's what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
$sql = "SELECT
    course_meta.parent_course,
    COUNT(DISTINCT resource.id) AS count
FROM
    course_meta
INNER JOIN resource ON course_meta.parent_course = resource.course
WHERE
    course_meta.child_course = $childcourse
GROUP BY course_meta.parent_course";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  echo 'Course "' . $result['parent_course'] . '" has " . $result['count'] . " resources.<br />';
}
```

Word of warning, if `$childcourse` is a string you'll need to enclose it in single-quotes here.

Also, are you sure the naming here is right? Surely a child course only has one parent course (and a parent course potentially having many child courses?).

Comment: thanks for the guidance. Im going to try Jim's first though. I inherited the naming, dosnt make sense to me either but they flipped it round.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT parent_course FROM course_meta where child_course = $childcourse"); 

$parentcourses = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```